# Word boundary search and exclamation mark at end of word

Tags: regex, vim, match, boundary

I can't find out how to search words with an exclamation mark at the end using boundaries.

p.e.
text:

```
Do this!
```

search:

```
/\<this!\>
```

This doesn't match `this!` in the text.
This either:

```
/\<this\!\>
```

I suppose that VIM thinks it must be Lookahead/Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertion.
How can I resolve this?

Comment: `!` is not part of a word so `\>` will not match after `!` but before it.

Comment: @Tensibai, it is only an example. I have many words with `!` at the end, I want to match some of them.

Comment: @Remonn yes. sorry, commented too quickly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `!` is not a keyword character (in your case, at least), so a regular expression assertion for a keyword to non-keyword boundary (which `\>` is) won't match after it. What *does* work is this

```
/\<this\>!/
```

But here, the `\>` is superfluous, as `s` clearly is a keyword character, and `!` isn't. So, only use the assertions where actually needed (like `\<` at the beginning in your example, to avoid matching `foothis!`), and all is well.

Alternatively, if for your purposes `!` belongs to a word, and you want to match it as such, include it via

```
:setlocal iskeyword+=!
```

and use `\k` for matching inside the word, e.g. `\<\k\{5}\>` to find all 5-letter (key)words.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (or replace `\w` with the character class your words consist of):

```
/\<\w\+\!
```

The `!` is not part of a word so any word boundary match like `\>` will match before, not after.

Comment: Don't understand why it is not part of a word. Is there no way to include it within the boundaries?

Comment: @Remonn: you need to understand that a word boundary is the position between a character from the character class `\w` and an other character that is not a member of this class (or the limit of the string).